# Presenting a view while processing another task in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I want to display an alert to notify the user while processing another task in the background queue (i.e, using another thread to process), then remove the alert when the task finishes. But I don't know how to do this. Thanks for your help.

```
    //Create alert
    alert = UIAlertController(title: "Logging in", message: "We are logging you in. Please wait for a few seconds...", preferredStyle: .alert)
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        //do task here
    }
    
    alert.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Please read http://www.programmingios.net/what-asynchronous-means/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the dismissal in the task.

```
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Logging in", message: "We are logging you in. Please wait for a few seconds...", preferredStyle: .alert)
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        //do task here
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            alert.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

However, an alert is poor interface for this. Use an activity indicator or a toast.

Comment: Matt, I am not familiar with the term "toast" and had to google it. It appears to be used on Android, but not iOS. You might want to define it for this audience.